# Iterating through a classname to click on all the related objects with the same classname in java for selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

With the test below when I am trying to iterate through the count of the elements so that all the elements that have been dragged onto a frame will be dropped back.

To accomplish that I have written the code below, where getClass seems to be necessary to get all the elements. When getClass is removed only two elements are found and what is more bizzare is that only one element is dropped back.

Can anyone explain why do I have to have "getClass" and is there a different way to get the entire class of a.ui-icon.ui-icon-refresh so that all the elements are clicked?

```
package Testing;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class Radiobuttons {


        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            WebElement SimplePhotoManager = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a"));
            SimplePhotoManager.click();
            driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/iframe")));
            WebElement source1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[1]"));
            WebElement source2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[2]"));
            WebElement source3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[3]"));
            WebElement source4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[4]"));
            WebElement targetBefore = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]"));
            Actions a = new Actions(driver);
            a.dragAndDrop(source1, targetBefore).build().perform();
            a.dragAndDrop(source2, targetBefore).build().perform();
            a.dragAndDrop(source3, targetBefore).build().perform();
            a.dragAndDrop(source4, targetBefore).build().perform();
            //Why is this required?
            List<WebElement> getClass= driver.findElements(By.className("a.ui-icon"));
            //Grab common attribute//Put into list and iterate
            int count=driver.findElements(By.className("ui-icon-refresh")).size();
            System.out.println(count);
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                driver.findElements(By.className("ui-icon-refresh")).get(i).click();
            }

            //Close the thing 
           //driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use an explicit wait here:

```
WebElement SimplePhotoManager = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a")));
        SimplePhotoManager.click();
```

because sometimes I have the exception that the element isn't clickable.

Regarding your problem, when you call:

```
List<WebElement> getClass= driver.findElements(By.className("a.ui-icon"));
```

actually, after, you don't do anything with this list.

The reason because after "it works" is because this call "lost" a bit of time and allows at the following call, this:

```
int count=driver.findElements(By.className("ui-icon-refresh")).size();
```

to "see" the list completely full.

In order to verify this, you can insert an explicit wait for the dropped element. For example, for the fist one:

```
WebElement first = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]/ul/li[1]")));
```

and wait before to go on.

Finally, inside your loop you call always the:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("ui-icon-refresh"))
```

isn't necessary do that.

You can call it once and after iterate on all the elements inside.

The entire code:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        WebElement SimplePhotoManager = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a")));
        SimplePhotoManager.click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/iframe")));
        WebElement source1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[1]"));
        WebElement source2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[2]"));
        WebElement source3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[3]"));
        WebElement source4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gallery\"]/li[4]"));
        WebElement targetBefore = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]"));
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        a.dragAndDrop(source1, targetBefore).build().perform();
        WebElement first = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]/ul/li[1]")));
        a.dragAndDrop(source2, targetBefore).build().perform();
        WebElement second = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]/ul/li[2]")));
        a.dragAndDrop(source3, targetBefore).build().perform();

        WebElement third = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]/ul/li[3]")));
        a.dragAndDrop(source4, targetBefore).build().perform();
        //Why is this required?
        WebElement fourth = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trash\"]/ul/li[4]")));


        System.out.println("-----------------");

        //List<WebElement> getClass= driver.findElements(By.className("a.ui-icon"));
        //Grab common attribute//Put into list and iterate

        List<WebElement> wel= driver.findElements(By.className("ui-icon-refresh"));
        int count= wel.size();
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        System.out.println(count);

        for(WebElement we: wel)
        {
            we.click();
        }
```